# How to spoof the source IP address of syslog messages?

Tags: linux, bash, syslog, netcat, rsyslog

I am trying to send syslog messages to a web server. I do not want my machine IP to be the sender IP of the syslog. Instead I have simulated a few IP addresses in my machine, say (10.0.100.1 - 10.0.100.10).

I want to send syslog messages from 10.0.100.1 instead of my local IP (192.168.0.1).

A shell/perl/logger command solution would be possible.

P.S. I am able to send syslog messages to /var/log/messages from my perl script with local IP as sender. So the only issue is I do not know how to set a different IP as the originating IP of the syslog.

Is there any possibility with ncat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493384/how-to-fake-source-ip-address-of-a-udp-packet

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The syslog UDP protocol is described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6

As you can see, HOSTNAME is a free-text field which you can set to any string you like.  Most of the standard libraries and tools don't let you set the hostname yourself, but you can pretty easily hack an open-source library to do it, or implement your own.

Comment: I mapped a new hostname to a virtual IP in /etc/hosts and I added $localHostName myHostName value in /etc/rsyslog.conf, yet my localIP is sent during the syslog message.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Net::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP) or [IP::Random](https://metacpan.org/pod/IP::Random)?

Comment: No, I mean, I want to send syslog messages with custom source IP address. I dont want the syslog messages to be sent with my local IP attached.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario and i used rsyslog module `omudpspoof` which did the trick for me.

You can configure a local rsyslog instance with the above module to spoof the source ip and then forward to the destination. For example:

On the system originating syslog messages, add the following in rsyslog config:

```
Module (
  load="omudpspoof"
)
Template (
  name="spoofaddr"
  type="string"
  string="10.10.10.50". # address to spoof
)
Action (
  type="omudpspoof"
  target="192.168.0.111". # your rsyslog server
  sourcetemplate="spoofaddr"
)
```

Then generate a test message

```
root@testmachine]# logger "test"
```

You can get more information regarding the rsyslog udp spoof module in their official page (link bellow):

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/modules/omudpspoof.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).